How to get Maven to use dependency reduced pom when building a multi-module project?
I encountered this confusing issue when working on a larger project, so I've created a simple reproduction project to better reproduce and explain my issue. I'm not sure if it is possible for me to upload a zip with the whole structure, but it is only 5 files: https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/f502a8e613a64aeeae671b4c41587c43.
EDIT: The 5 files in my reproduction are also included at the bottom of this question -- not just on an external site -- as requested. I initially figured it would unnecessarily clutter this page due to the general verbosity of Maven.

I have a parent module MavenTest with 3 submodules: A, B, and C.
A only contains the class org.example.maventest.A.
B shades A like so:
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <relocations>
                            <relocation>
                                <pattern>org.example.maventest</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>org.example.maventest.a</shadedPattern>
                            </relocation>
                        </relocations>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

This relocates the org.example.maventest.A class to org.example.maventest.a.A.
C shades B like so:
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

This should simply shade in the relocated org.example.maventest.a.A class from module B into C's jar.

Expected behavior: running mvn clean install to build all the modules should create a jar C that only includes the relocated org.example.maventest.a.A file.
Actual behavior: When the shade plugin runs for module C, it reports this:
[INFO] --- shade:3.6.0:shade (default) @ C ---
[INFO] Including org.example:B:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Including org.example:A:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Dependency-reduced POM written at: /MavenTest/C/dependency-reduced-pom.xml

It seems that module C is inheriting the module A dependency from module B, which causes the original A class to be shaded in as well (using IntelliJ to look inside the jar):


The strange part, is that if I only build module C using mvn clean install -pl :C, maven correctly only includes the relocated class A:
[INFO] --- shade:3.6.0:shade (default) @ C ---
[INFO] Including org.example:B:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in the shaded jar.
[INFO] Dependency-reduced POM written at: /MavenTest/C/dependency-reduced-pom.xml


It seems that in this case, module C is looking at the dependency reduced pom of B produced by the shade plugin where the compile dependency on module A is removed. So, during the full build, I want to reproduce this behavior of C looking at B's dependency reduced pom.
This also seems to affect compilation. For example, if I add this class to module C:
public class C {
    org.example.maventest.A first = null;
    org.example.maventest.a.A second = null;
}

When I run the full build (or look at it statically with IntelliJ), this code compiles.

However, when I build module C independently, this code fails because the org.example.maventest.A class cannot be found. I want the behavior of the independent build, where module A is seemingly excluded from the compile classpath.

Reproduction files
Directory structure:

MavenTest/A/src/main/java/org/example/maventest/A.java
    
package org.example.maventest;
 
public class A {
}

MavenTest/A/pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>MavenTest</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
 
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
</project>

MavenTest/B/pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>MavenTest</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
 
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
 
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>A</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
 
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <relocations>
                                <relocation>
                                    <pattern>org.example.maventest</pattern>
                                    <shadedPattern>org.example.maventest.a</shadedPattern>
                                </relocation>
                            </relocations>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

MavenTest/C/pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>MavenTest</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
 
    <artifactId>C</artifactId>
 
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>B</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
 
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

MavenTest/pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavenTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>A</module>
        <module>B</module>
        <module>C</module>
    </modules>
</project>


Output of running Maven
(I tried to include these directly in the question, but StackOverflow complained I exceeded the maximum amount of characters).
mvn clean install (Full build, incorrect final C jar): https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/ce82a48c1db14a7f9c7c86020b4b79d6
mvn clean install -pl :C -X (Just module C, correct final jar): https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/dc7c21fcbb6442619a8159d0a0315e0c

It seems this was reported as an issue with Maven about 9 years ago: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5899. It seems it has not yet been resolved.

Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.
Then add your code to the question itself, not on an external site.

Also add the output you get from maven, when you use the -X option.

Added the reproduction files directly to the question. I couldn't add the Maven output with -X directly to the question because it took up too many characters, but they are included via an external site.
